# MsgBox caused charts to appear as blank

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I have created code to fit a model to some data and then create a chart comparing measured/fitted data. I want to include a msgbox so that the user can check that the chart shows a decent fit and then OK it to continue. Even though the code for the msgbox is after the creation of the charts (right at the end of the sub), the charts are displayed as blank while the msgbox is shown. The charts display properly after either yes or no is selected in the msgbox. I have tried, pausing the sub for a few seconds, refressing the charts, calling a separate sub for the message box but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your code, thanks.

Comment: ok, will do. i am new to Stackoverflow so let me work out how to format the code properly before i post it, it looks a mess when i just copy and paste. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, we can help you fix the format too.