# VBA chart won't display while MSGBOX is active

Tags: excel, vba

Hi My Problem is identical to this unanswered question from a while ago

[MsgBox caused charts to appear as blank](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59911758/21400208)

Basically I'm doing some quality control in excel and trying to utilise VBA to make it easier, my code runs through a column until it finds the next chunk of flagged data, it then creates a chart of that and surrounding data for visual inspection, I then added an error box for the user to input whether they believe the error flags for that data should be deleted or not, however the chart wont actually display or render until the user interacts with the msgbox, since the chart can be viewed in the background I was hoping the user could just use this macro, quickly view the chart, say yes or no, and the error flags are either deleted or not, and the script moves on to the next flagged series of data. First time here, please feel free to let me know if any of this is not in the right format. Code below:

```
Dim SelRange As Range
Dim ExtRange As Range
Dim cht As Object
Dim errorflag As String



Selection.End(xlDown).Select

errorflag = ActiveCell

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select

Set SelRange = Selection

Set ExtRange = SelRange.Offset(-SelRange.Rows.Count).Resize(3 * SelRange.Rows.Count)

ExtRange.Select

Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ExtRange
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = errorflag & " error flag of hydrograph of " & Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value



MsgBox "Do you wish to delete the selected error flags?", vbYesNo

If Result = vbYes Then
SelRange.Clear

End If
```

I have tried as separate subs but then I can't delete the variables I want as they are declared in the previous sub.

I've tried adding pauses.

I've tried adding a second intermediary msgbox.

Comment: Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` right before the message box.

Comment: Chart still won't display, thank you though

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow Excel to process the Chart after you create it and before the message box.  The function to achieve that is `DoEvents`

In this case (and some others), you need to call `DoEvents` twice.

Demo

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cht As Shape
    Set rng = [c4:d8]
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
    cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this depends on the processing speed of your machine because two `DoEvents` didn't work for me but three did.

Comment: @kairu thats good to know.

Comment: You could do a Userform and show the Message in a label or so after the chart creation
UserForm1.Show vbModal
then you do not need a doevents

Comment: @red you could.  But why thr aversion to DoEvents?

Comment: @ chris neilsen  Imho doevents just do what it says it just will do any tasks in the windows queue. Sometimes you need (e.g. for web returns, cause in vba there are no tasks to solve this problem).
But if you see, that in this example it is also a question of how many doevents, i would always prefer another solution. 
I go with "DoEvents can help in VBA but it can also backfire"

But it was anyway only a suggestion

Comment: It is hard to improve on this answer! Here is a one line VBA delay subroutine - `Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay: DoEvents: Next i: End Sub` which will give you as many DoEvents as you want.

Comment: Ended up copying and pasting as image which achieved what I needed, but think will need this type of solution, or the different sub solution, later in the project so thanks a lot for the answer and explanation

Answer (score 0):

Put your message in a Sub of its own, together with the actions coming from the answer.

```
Sub YourMessage()
    If MsgBox("Do you wish to delete the selected error flags?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Then call it like this

```
Application.OnTime Now, "YourMessage"
```

Note that you can't use local variables in this call.

Comment: Ahh was trying this method but the local variables was tripping me up. Thanks